# Update HashMap values of type HashSet<Integer>

Tags: java, hashmap

I have trouble updating the HashMap values of Set type. After initializing the HashMap with key-values pair, I want to insert a new value to the the existing value Set, and the new value is to be incremented for each insert. My code is following:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] mapKeys = new String[]{"hello", "world", "america"};
        Map<String, Set<Integer>> hashMap1 = new HashMap<String, Set<Integer>>();
        Set<Integer> values = new HashSet<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)  // initialize the values to a set of integers[1 through 9]
        {
            values.add(i);
        }

        for (String key : mapKeys)
        {
            hashMap1.put(key, values);
        }

        StdOut.println("hashMap1 is: " + hashMap1.toString());

        int newValues = 100; // insert this newValues (incremented at each insert) to each value
        Set<Integer> valuesCopy;

        for (String key : mapKeys)
        {
            if (hashMap1.containsKey(key))
            {
                valuesCopy = hashMap1.get(key); // first, copy out the existing values

                valuesCopy.add(newValues++); // insert the newValues to the value Set
                hashMap1.remove(key);// remove the existing entries
                hashMap1.put(key, valuesCopy); // insert the key-value pairs

            }
        }

        StdOut.println("the updated hashMap1 is: " + hashMap1.toString());


    }
```

When executing the code, each HashMap key is associated with the same set of Integers:
[102, 0, 1, 2, 100, 3, 101, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], however, what I really want is insert only one number to each set, this is what I want: [0, 1, 2, 100, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

I need help understanding this: why all the new inserted values are the same? how to make it work as I wish? thanks for help

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that the *every object symbol in Java is a reference to the actual object*. In this part

```
for (String key : mapKeys)
{
    hashMap1.put(key, values);
}
```

you associate each key with the reference to the same `Set<Integer>`, so when you change one of them, all of them are changed.

The correct way to do this is

```
for (String key : mapKeys)
{
    hashMap1.put(key, new HashSet<Integer>(values));
}
```

This way every key will have its own copy of `Set` initialized with the content of `values`.

With this fact, you can also see that the code here

```
            valuesCopy = hashMap1.get(key); // first, copy out the existing values

            valuesCopy.add(newValues++); // insert the newValues to the value Set
            hashMap1.remove(key);// remove the existing entries
            hashMap1.put(key, valuesCopy); // insert the key-value pairs
```

is verbose and introduces unnecessary overhead. Simply use

```
hashMap1.get(key).add(newValues++);
```

Comment: but when I do hashMap1.put(key, hashMap1.get(key).add(newValues++)); it gives me data-type incompatible error.

Comment: @TonyGW: You don't use `put` again. The `get` returns a reference to the underlying `HashSet`. So when you calls the `add` function on it, the original one associated with your key changes too.

Comment: @TonyGW: You still don't understand the idea of *reference*, do you?

Comment: this: hashMap1.get(key).add(newValues++); does not work for me. It gives this wrong result: [102, 0, 1, 2, 100, 3, 101, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] in the HashMap values, which should be [0, 1, 2, 100, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

Comment: @TonyGW: Because you didn't adopt this change: `hashMap1.put(key, new HashSet<Integer>(values));`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when you execute `if (hashMap1.containsKey(key))`, the java loops to check each key to check existence of key **automatically**, so that you don't need to write the for loop code by yourself.

Then, you don't need to write `hashMap1.remove(key)` because that when insert a exist key to java map, the map will find the existed (key, value) pair and overwrite the new (key, value) pair.

Here is the modified code after `Set<Integer> valuesCopy;`:

```
if (hashMap1.containsKey(key))
{
    valuesCopy = hashMap1.get(key); // first, copy out the existing values
    valuesCopy.add(newValues++); // insert the newValues to the value Set
    hashMap1.put(key, valuesCopy); // insert the key-value pairs
}
```

Just remove `for (String key : mapKeys)` and `hashMap1.remove(key)` code segment, and then you may get the result that you want.

Comment: thanks, but I need to insert the new value to the existing values in the map. So I guess I need to get the existing values based on the key. right?

Comment: Correct! You have to get the exist (key,value) pair, modify the value and just put (key, new_value) back the map. (no need to remove the existed (key, value) pair)